# How to maintain a state in a property, which needs to be accessed from different classes in a (kind of) parent/child relationship?

Tags: c#, properties, getter-setter

I have a more complex structure, where some "child" classes are added to the "parent" class as subview. Thereby I have variable called `currentSelectedDate`, which should be accessible in all of the connected classes. My current structure looks like the following:

Class A (top most "parent"):

```
private DateTime currentSelectedDate;
public DateTime CurrentSelectedDate {
    get
    {
        if (this.dayHeader != null)
        {
            return this.dayHeader.CurrentSelectedDate;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.currentSelectedDate;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        this.currentSelectedDate = value;
        if (this.dayHeader != null)
        {
            this.dayHeader.CurrentSelectedDate = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Class B ("child" of A/dayHeader):

```
private DateTime currentSelectedDate;
public DateTime CurrentSelectedDate {
    get
    {
        if (this.weekdayScroller != null)
        {
            return this.weekdayScroller.CurrentSelectedDate;
        }
        else
        {
            return this.currentSelectedDate;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        this.currentSelectedDate = value;
        if (this.weekdayScroller != null)
        {
            this.weekdayScroller.CurrentSelectedDate = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Class C ("child" of B / weekdayScroller):

```
public DateTime CurrentSelectedDate { get; set; }
```

Here only the direction from the parent to the child is shown, where the properties are used to spread the data. In the backwards direction I use events. The disadvantage of this approach is that I have to store the values multiple times in each class. Also if I'm in one class, I have to set the value of `this.currentSelectedDate`, but also in the other class (e.g. `dayHeader.CurrentSelectedDate`) manually (the setter/getter should only be used by external calls).

For class A the class C (weekdayScroller) is hidden.

Class C (weekdayScroller) is used by other classes too, so I have to maintain the property `currentSelectedDate` directly in it.

One has also to be aware of when something is initialized. E.g. on the creation of class A the `currentSelectedDate` is set, but class B isn't existing yet. Therefore the `null` checks.

My question now is if this is a good way of handling the spreading of the state between all classes or if there are better ways.

Comment: You should be marking `CurrentSelectedDate` property in the parent class as `virtual` and overriding them in the derived classes. As you have it now, you are hiding them, not overriding (and you should be getting a compiler warning).

Comment: There is no subclassing involved here. I only share the variable.

Comment: If there isn't subclassing, I wouldn't use the terms "parent" and "child", can you show how these classes relate to each other then? Its not clear from your terminology.

Comment: You can imagine that as different views, which are stacked together. There is a kind of parent/child relationship, but only as graphical represenation, which needs to communicate between each other.

Comment: It depends on the type of application that you created. Console, winform, universal...
If for example is a console application, you can declare a class in public and initialize an object of this class in _Main_
Then in the other classes that you declare you can pass in parameters of their constructor or of a method, a reference to this object.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette: It is a Xamarin application. So I would take the main entry point of my application (AppDelegate) and create the state property/class there, which should be accessible in all my classes. Seems not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a better way? Not that I am aware of. I understand the drawbacks of this design.

If there is just a single value of the variable to set (so parent-child relation is 1:1), why not put it in a shared class which you reference everywhere. It is virtually the same, but it might be easier to have an overview of what happens where and whose responsibility it is.

Comment: You mean something like a Singleton?

Comment: More like an state object that is shared across the classes. It seems you have some calendar like thing and you want to share some properties. I guess those should be split off to a separate class. You can expose that one directly to the outside of each class or wrap its properties. One updated the other since there is just one instance.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a short example demonstrating your approach. So that I can see if it would fit my needs. What is not so clear for me is how you share your state object between the different classes.

Comment: You create a class, `ViewState`, which you instantiate in the parent. You pass that to the children when you create or register them. If the UI sets the 'date' field, it is updated along all references since they use the same instance.

Comment: OK, pass-by-reference is used here.

Comment: Well, yes. It are objects :).